# Confusion about transversality at a point

Tags: differential-geometry, transversality

When reading this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498522/inverse-image-of-a-sub-manifold-transversal-intersection), I become confused about what it means for a map to intersect transversally.  To help conceptualize things better here's my question.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a once continuously differentiable function, $d\geq n>0$ be (positive) integers, and let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  When does $f$ intersect transversally with $x$?

Comment: Let $g:\mathbb{R}^0\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be defined by $g(0)=p$. The maps $f$ and $g$ are transversal when for all $t\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(t)=x=g(0)$ one has that the image of $df$ and the image of $dg$ (which in our case is only the $0$ space), generate all of the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ at $x$. Since $dg$ only contributes $0$ then the image of $df$ would have to do all the job. One would need $df$ to be onto for all $t$ such that $f(t)=x$.

Comment: I think that some other examples are going to be more interesting. For example (1) $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x)=(x,x^2)$, $g(x)=(x,0)$. (2) With the same spaces are before, but with $f(x)=(x,x^2)$ and $g(x)=(x,x)$. (3) $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $f(x)=(x,x^2,0)$, $g(x)=(x,x,0)$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Thanks; I would happily accept these comments as a formal answer.

Comment: You can write it out properly, maybe even work out the other examples and add your own answer.

Comment: two maps $f,g:M\rightarrow N$ intersect transversally at $m\in M$ if $f(m)=g(m)=n$ and $f_{*,m}(T_mM)+g_{*,m}(T_mM)=T_{*,n}N$.. can you now guess what should be definition for transversal intersection as you mentioned?

Comment: So g in this case is taken to be the identity map?